# Draw sin(x)/x to PictureBox in animation mode by Timer component

Tags: c#, graphics, timer, drawing, picturebox

I need to draw sin(x)/x graphic into PictureBox in animation mode by timer component. I have axes already on my picBox and graphic draws from 0;0. Also I have some code from this forum, but there my graphic draws FROM RIGHT TO THE LEFT, and I need to draw it FROM LEFT TO THE RIGHT. And I need to draw it in animation mode by timer. Could anybody help me?
Here's my drawing function:

```
private void drawStream()
    {
        const int scaleX = 35;
        const int scaleY = 35;

        Point picBoxTopLeft = new Point(0, 0);
        Point picBoxTopLeftm1 = new Point(-1, 0);          

        int halfX = picBox.Width / 2; 
        int halfY = picBox.Height / 2; 
        Size size = new Size(halfX + 20, picBox.Height);

        Graphics gr = picBox.CreateGraphics();
        gr.TranslateTransform(halfX, halfY);

        gr.ScaleTransform(scaleX, scaleY);

        gr.ResetClip();

        float lastY = (float)Math.Sin(0);
        float y = lastY;
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 0.015F);
        float stepX = 1F / scaleX; 

        for (float x = 0; x < 15; x += stepX)
        {
            gr.CopyFromScreen(picBox.PointToScreen(picBoxTopLeft), picBoxTopLeftm1, size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);             
            y = (float)Math.Sin(x);
            gr.DrawLine(p, -stepX, lastY, 0, y);
            lastY = y;                
        } 
    }
```

Thanx a lot.
P.S. Sorry for my English, I'm Ukrainian.

Comment: Make sure you dispose your `Pen` when you're finished.  Put it in a `using` statement.

Comment: Thanx, but I use it Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 0.015F).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the line:

```
gr.DrawLine(p, -stepX, lastY, 0, y);
```

Will always draw a line from (-stepX, lastY) to (0, y).  Only the Y coordinates of these points change during your loop which doesn't look like what you want.

Moreover, you're stepping in the X direction by `stepX` which is defined as being 1 / 35.0f.  This means you're stepping 35 times per whole pixel; a bit excessive.  Get rid of your `ScaleTransform` and instead scale your independent variable (x) to get a more sensible frequency.  You should probably also increase your `amplitude` to get  a good looking curve as well.

I think your drawing loop should look more like:

```
for (int x = 1; x < halfX; x += 1)
{           
  y = (float) amplitude * Math.Sin(x * stepX);
  gr.DrawLine(p, x - 1, lastY, x, y);
  lastY = y;                
}
```

This will draw from the origin (0,0) to the right side of the picture box at once.  To animate this you're going to need to take this code and instead of looping all the way to `halfX` you want to loop only part of the way and keep track of where you the next time your `Timer` fires it's event.

edit:

Every time you create a `Pen` object you take a handle from Windows through GDI.  These handles are only returned to be reused when you `Dispose()` the `Pen` object.  If you create a new Pen every time you draw and don't dispose them you'll run out of handles eventually!

To be safe when using these types of objects (`Pen`, `Brush`, `Font`, and more need to be disposed) wrap them in a `using` statement:

```
using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 0.015f)) {
  // ... use the pen here
}
// After here it is Disposed and cannot be accessed
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, spent 20 minutes to try it myself.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
    pictureBox1.Image = _bitmap;

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    timer.Interval = 10;

    timer.Start();
}

private int x = 0;
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(++x < _bitmap.Width)
    {
        int y = _bitmap.Height/2 
                - ((int)(Math.Sin(x * (Math.PI * 2) /  _bitmap.Width) * (_bitmap.Height / 2)));

        //Small rounding error
        if (y > _bitmap.Height - 1)
            y = _bitmap.Height - 1;

        _bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
    }
    pictureBox1.Image = _bitmap;
}
```

Tested and working.

Comment: Well done nice and simple to understand and good example, one thing I must stress if you are going to declare a Bitmap object _bitmap then ensure you do so in any of your examples you provide on stackflow so others can learn from it. Otherwise its incomplete example

Answer (score 0):

You should really add Points to a `GraphicsPath` and just paint that.

Also: You should not create a Graphics object like that. Get one from the `Bitmap` or use the one supplied by the `Paint` event.

Answer (score -1):

1) Right to left. Just change your for loop.

> for (float x = 0; x < 15; x += stepX)

becomes

> for (float x = size.Width; x >= 0; x
>   -= stepX)

2) A timer.

Simple solution is to just add a sleep.

```
 for (float x = 0; x < 15; x += stepX)
 Thread.Sleep(500); //draw...
```

Comment: -1, the Thread.Sleep will not return control to the GUI and in effect, lock it up.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have labor to use TIMER. Strange but nothing has changed, my graphic still draws from left to right.

Comment: Yes, using a sleep will block the main thread. Using a timer should fix it.